# Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm developing a webapp on Azure that creates an application with signalr.

Localhost I can communicate normally, but when I publish to Azure, I receive a Handshake error.

I have no idea what it could be.
[image: Error Messages]

Error: Connection disconnected with error

> 'Error: Server returned handshake error: Handshake was canceled.'

I added the redis backplane to see if this was the problem, but the problem persisted

I have this code on backend:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSignalRWebApi(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var redisConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
    const string channelName = "CustomerPosition";

    if (redisConnectionString is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(redisConnectionString));

    services
        .AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            options.AddFilter<CustomerInformationFilter>();
            options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        })
        .AddStackExchangeRedis(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionFactory = async writer =>
            {
                var config = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(redisConnectionString);
                config.ChannelPrefix = channelName;

                var connection = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(config, writer);
                connection.ConnectionFailed += async (_, _) =>
                {
                    await RedisBackplaneDisconnectHandler.ReleaseConnections();
                };
                return connection;
            };
        });

    services.AddSingleton<IConnectionsManager, ConnectionsManager>();
    services.AddSingleton<CustomerInformationFilter>();
    return services;
}



public static IEndpointRouteBuilder UseSignalR(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    endpoints.MapHub<CustomerPatrimonyHub>("/sse/customer/patrimony",
        options => { options.Transports = HttpTransportType.ServerSentEvents; });

    RedisBackplaneDisconnectHandler.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IConnectionsManager>());

    return endpoints;
}
```

---

And my front-end looks like this

```
const setupConnection = (bearerToken) => {
return new Promise(resolve => {

    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(`https://UrlToApplicationInAzure`, {
            accessTokenFactory: (() => {
                return bearerToken;
            }),
            skipNegotiation: true
        })
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
        .build();

    connection.on("CustomerPatrimonyChanged", (data) => {
        const customerCodeValueDiv = document.getElementById("customerCodeValue");
        customerCodeValueDiv.innerHTML = data.customerCode;

        const patrimonyValueValueDiv = document.getElementById("patrimonyValue");
        patrimonyValueValueDiv.innerHTML = data.patrimony;

    });

    connection.on("Finished", () => {
        connection.stop();
    });

    connection.start()
        .then(() => resolve(connection))
        .catch(err => console.error('Start: ', err.toString()));

    connection.onclose(() => {
        console.log('OnClose - Disconnected: ', connection.state === signalR.HubConnectionState.Disconnected);
    });
})
  };

 const handler = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

const bearerTokenElement = document.getElementById("bearerToken");

setupConnection(bearerTokenElement.value)
    .then(conn => {
        conn.invoke("LoadCustomerPatrimony")
            .catch(err => console.error('Get Customer Patrimony Update: ', err.toString()));
    });
```

};
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", handler);

---

I tried to activate websockets on Azure, but the option doesn't appear for me: [Azure Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7NYe.png)

Comment: Have you tried to turn on Web Sockets in Azure Portal?
If not, go to AppServices then Configuration then General Settings then Web sockets then switch ON. This should solve your issue

Comment: @Erisonson please share  the code you tried

Comment: From the screenshot, it's using SSE, not websocket. Could you kindly which protocol  you are using in development?

Comment: And please try to use websocket and check the issue again. If still not  works, you should enable the [server side logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-8.0#server-side-logging) to get more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem! In my case, the problem was in the application's DNS security policies. And I also needed to configure Sticky Sessions on my load balancer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).